# node:node_memory_swap_io_bytes:sum_rate metric missing in latest versions

Tags: prometheus-node-exporter, kube-state-metrics

I've been monitoring the metric named "node:node_memory_swap_io_bytes:sum_rate" successfully using kube-state-metric (Version: v1.9.2) and Node-exporter (Version: v0.18.1).
Now, I'm seeking assistance in locating the same metric while using the following versions:
kube-state-metric: 2.5.0
Node-exporter: v1.3.1-1

on the latest version, i unable to see the metric name in prometheus also.

Comment: Name of your metric suggests that it is in fact a metric generated by recording rule. Are you using same Prometheus with the same recording rules?